# Additional permission for facebook by dotnetopenauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-authentication

I am new in dotnetopenauth and facebooksdk.net. I am using dotnetopenauth for authentication of app by user and provide a custom list of scope for permission.It is working fine.

But I need a multistage permission. For example at first user will permit for basic details, email and extended profile. After some time based on condition we need read_insights permission from the user. I am getting any example regarding this.

For read_insights permission I am currently redirecting to user to facebook login dialog with earlier scope with read_insights. In this scenario a second dialog for read_insights permission is not appear as it is optional.

However is there any way so that I will send access_token and a dialog will appear only for permitting read_insights ?

Comment: Take a look this article [LINK](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services)

Comment: Daniel, I think this is for combining different social sites authentication.However I need new permission from user for facebook as  there are already some permission by user to my app.

Comment: you need two permissions for each user in your app, or one for app and other to site?